# Pass input when using 'a' tag with routerLink

Tags: angular

I have an object called user that i want to pass to child component user.component when using 'a' tag in order to create clickable div that routes to that component.

In user component i have the following.

```
@Input()
user: user;
```

When i use the component tag it works.

```
<app-user [user]=user></app-user>
```

When i try to use 'routerLink' with 'a' tag it doesn't.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user-dashboard/user', user]">
```

How can i pass the user object as argument with 'a' tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely don't want to pass the entire object as a route.

I think what you're trying to do is route to some page like `/user-dashboard/user/x` where x is the user's id.

In that case you need to pass the `id` property (or whatever your primary key attribute is called) of the user to the RouterLink, instead of the entire object:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user-dashboard/user', user.id]">
```

If you want to pass the `User` objects attributes to the new component you have a few options:

1. Re-fetch it from the new component (you have access to the `:id` param through the `ActivatedRoute` class) so you should be able to query your API for this specific user.
2. Create a service to share the details when you navigate, and re-fetch it through the service in the new component.
3. (*don't do this*) You could `JSON.stringify` your user object and pass that as the route parameter like `[routerLink]="['/user-dashboard/user', JSON.stringify(user)]">`.

Comment: But i want all of the user's properties, not just the id

Comment: That shouldn't be handled in the routing however. Instead either re-fetch it from the id in the other component, or share the data through a service. (although you could do it from the route by doing `JSON.stringify(user)` in your `routerLink`, but that's a really bad practice)